# SQL to bucket numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

so i am trying to bucket business days into buckets but I am getting stuck:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('mattexcel2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE mattexcel2 PRINT ' DROP TEMP TABLE'
SELECT * INTO mattexcel2 FROM SA_MASTER_BASE PRINT ' INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE'
GO
ALTER TABLE mattexcel2 ADD [Bucket] NVARCHAR(255) PRINT 'Bucket'
GO
UPDATE mattexcel2 SET [Bucket] = '0-3 Days' where [Business days in current Status] <= 3
GO
```

When I run this in SQL I get:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1.91' to data
>   type int.

So I want 1.9 to fall under my Bucket column as 0-3 Days.

Comment: Who is... [Business days in current Status]

Comment: What data type has `[SA_MASTER_BASE].[Business days in current Status]`? `nvarchar` by any chance?

Comment: Yup all in NVARCHAR. Business days is how long that line item has been sitting there in that status.

Comment: Then there you have it. You compare `[Business days in current Status]`, which is a `nvarchar` to `3` which is an `integer`. The engine tries to cast `[Business days in current Status]` to `integer` and fails. Use proper datatypes and/or literals to correct it.

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '162.91' to data type int.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is:

```
[Business days in current Status] <= 3
```

Because `[Business days in current Status]` is a string, it needs to be converted to a number for the comparison.  SQL Server chooses an integer.  You can fix this by using a decimal place:

```
UPDATE mattexcel2
    SET [Bucket] = '0-3 Days' 
    WHERE try_convert(decimal(38, 4), [Business days in current Status]) <= 3.0;
```

However, I would suggest that you use a computed column:

```
alter table mattexcel2
    add bd_bucket as (case when try_convert(decimal(38, 4), [Business days in current Status]) <= 3.0
                           then '0-3 Days'
                      end);
```

A computed column will always have the right value, without being updated.

Comment: thanks, iv tried this too but then i get Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

Comment: @Lalaland . . . You have some very strange values, which you should investigate.  I modified the answer to use `try_convert()` to work around the problem in the meantime.